# Getting an error when using delete[] cpp

Tags: c++, delete-operator

Heap corruption detected after normal block #151 when i try to use `delete[]` in my code

```
#include "Queue.h"

void main() {
    queue* stk = new queue;
    initQueue(stk, 4);
    enqueue(stk, 9);
    enqueue(stk, 4);
    enqueue(stk, 3);
    enqueue(stk, 7);

    while (!isEmpty(stk)) {
        std::cout << "Popping number:" << dequeue(stk) << std::endl;
    }

    cleanQueue(stk);
    delete stk;

    system("Pause");
}
```

This is the delete function :

```
void cleanQueue(queue* q) {
    delete[] q->_elements;
}
```

this is the struct :

```
typedef struct queue
{
    int * _elements;
    int _maxSize;
    int _count;
} queue;
```

Can someone please tell me why this is happening and what should i do to fix it?
Thanks.

```
        #include "Queue.h"
void enqueue(queue* q, unsigned int newValue) {
    int i = 0;
    if (!isFull(q)) {
        q->_count++;
        q->_elements[0] = newValue;
        for (i = q->_count; i > 0; i--) {
            q->_elements[i] = q->_elements[i - 1];
        }
    }
}

int dequeue(queue* q) {
    int ans = -1;

    if (!isEmpty(q)) {
        ans = q->_elements[q->_count];
        q->_count--;

    }
    return(ans);
}

void initQueue(queue* q, unsigned int size) {
    q->_count = 0;
    q->_maxSize = size;
    q->_elements = new int[size];
}

void cleanQueue(queue* q) {
    delete[] q->_elements;
}

bool isFull(queue* q) {
    return(q->_count == q->_maxSize);
}

bool isEmpty(queue* q) {
    return(q->_count == 0);
}
```

Comment: Please show the implementation of enqueue

Comment: can you show the constructor of `queue` and other places where you set/access `_elements`?

Comment: `typedef struct queue` in c++ we don't need `typedef` here.

Comment: In addition to what's already been told: why isn't `initQueue`, and `enqueue` implemented as methods of `queue` class?

Comment: You need to `delete` what you `new`ed and you need to `delete[]` what you `new[]`ed.

Comment: I just had my first lesson in cpp so if u can explain yourself it will be nice. thanks

Comment: `for (i = q->_count; i > 0; i--) {` looks like an out of bounds access. Hopefully _count is always less than size.

Comment: how is that out of bounds

Comment: If _count == _maxSize then you access out of bounds here: `q->_elements[i] = q->_elements[i - 1];` because `q->_elements[_maxSize]` is out of bounds.

Comment: but if count == maxSize it wont continue there is an IF to check if they equals

Comment: Yes it will. You incremented _count:  `q->_count++;` after the check. if _count was 1 less than _maxSize before the check you have an out of bounds after the increment.

Comment: but if its not full then it will be fine to do q->count++ because if its not full we can add one untill it will reach the limit

Comment: Again it is not fine  if _count was 1 less than _maxSize  because you increment after checking. After the increment _count = _maxSize but you still go on.

Comment: OHH i think i understand thank you

Comment: Yeah its working now thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine your queue has one element in it, and your maxSize is also 1.
It's not empty, so you proceed to read the value at _count in elements.
So it reads elements[1] (since _count is 1) when the only element is at elements[0].  If that goes past the end of your allocation, you will have a memory error (undefined behavior) but you always will be reading the wrong value.

```
int dequeue(queue* q) {
    int ans = -1;

    if (!isEmpty(q)) {
        ans = q->_elements[q->_count];
        q->_count--;

    }
    return(ans);
}
```

You probably want to subtract one from _count.

Your enqueue looks to have a logical error too, since you move your elements *after* you write your new value, so you overwrote something.

```
void enqueue(queue* q, unsigned int newValue) {
    int i = 0;
    if (!isFull(q)) {
        q->_count++;
        q->_elements[0] = newValue; // <<<<<<<< Here.
        for (i = q->_count; i > 0; i--) {
            q->_elements[i] = q->_elements[i - 1];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your enqueue function the value of count reaches 4. You then try to access it in your for loop as q->elements[4] while the highest index in your array is 3.

Answer (score 0):

As Alex mentioned, your `enqueue()` function has a bug. Try the following code.

```
void enqueue(queue* q, unsigned int newValue) {
    int i = 0;
    if (!isFull(q)) {
        for (i = q->_count; i > 0; i--) {
            q->_elements[i] = q->_elements[i - 1];
        }
        q->_elements[0] = newValue;
        q->_count++;
    }
}
```